# Get all image src from array of image src and placing them into div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have I array of images src `["http://src1", "http://src2", "http://src3"]`. I want for get all images from that array and manipulate them, for example placing them into a div?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Are you sure it's `["http://src1,http://src2,http://src3"]`? Or is it rather `["http://src1", "http://src2", "http://src3"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HTML

```
 <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Images</h1>
            <div id="content">
            </div>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

## JS

```
var imageSources = ["http://src1,http://src2,http://src3"]

    imageSources.forEach(element => {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.width = '300';
        img.height = '300';
        img.src = element;
        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(img)
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var imgSrc = ["http://src1,http://src2,http://src3"];

var string = imgSrc[0];
console.log(string);
var array = string.split(",");
console.log(array);


  var inHTML = '';
  
console.log(array[0]);

 $.each(array, function(key, value){

var html = '<img src="'+ value[key]+'" align="center">';
  inHTML += html;  

});

 $('div#item').html(inHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item"></div>
```

You can append the dynamically created Images from the array to a perticular div. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think your array is somewhat like:

```
["http://src1","http://src2","http://src3"]
```

If I am right then you can do something like:

```
var y = x.map((key,value)=>{return ('<div>'+key+'</div>')});
```

y will be an array with the div tags containing images.

Hope, I understood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want for get all images from that array and manipulate them, for
>   example placing them into a div

You can dynamically generate `img` elements and add them to a `div`.

To iterate through the array you could use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), creating the `img` elements within the loop using [**createElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [**appendChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to append the image to the `div`

See example below, which should get you started.

```js
var images = ["https://placehold.it/50x50","https://placehold.it/25x25","https://placehold.it/75x75"];

var target = document.getElementById('target');

images.forEach(function(imgSrc){
  var newImg = document.createElement("img");
  newImg.src = imgSrc;
  target.appendChild(newImg);
})
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating an Array:**

You must use the following syntax to to create a JavaScript Array:

```
var array_name = [ item1, item2, ... ];
```

Or Using the JavaScript Keyword new:

```
var array_name = new Array( item1, item2, ... );
```

So your array must be like this:

```
var image_source = [ 'http://src1', 'http://src2', 'http://src3' ];
```

**Access the Elements of an Array:**

You refer to an array element by referring to the index number. for example this statement accesses the value of the first element in cars:

```
var first_image = image_source[ 0 ];
```

**Example:**

```js
var image_source = [ 'http://img1', 'http://img2', 'http://img3' ];
document.getElementById( 'demo' ).innerHTML = image_source[ 1 ];
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```